# Dynamically create page based on ListModel count

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout, loader

I am a beginner QT/QML app development

How can I create a qml dynamically based on the ListModel count.
In the view I am listing the modelObjects in a GridLayout using Repeater.

```
Item{
      id:griditem
      anchors.fill:parent

          GridLayout{
               id: grid2
               x:145
               y:30
               Layout.preferredHeight: 480
               Layout.preferredWidth: 1135
               rowSpacing:10
               columnSpacing:40

               columns: 3
               rows: 2

               Repeater{
                   id: repeater_Id
                   model: FeatureModel{}

                   Loader{
                       id: loader_Id

                       source: "QuadTiles.qml"
                       onLoaded: {
                             loader_Id.item.nIndex=index
                             loader_Id.item.type_String = type

                             loader_Id.item.title_Text.text = title
                             loader_Id.item.description_Text.text = description
                             loader_Id.item.btn1_icon.source = icon1

                       }
                   }
               } //Repeater
          }//GridLayout
  }
```

**Edit :**
I am facing some issues
I need to create new views dynamically based on the ModelList count. Each page having maximum 6 item (3 rows and 2 columns) in GridLayout

'QuadTiles.qml' is the qml file which is load in to each item of GridLayout

Comment: I totally do not get what you try to achive. What is a *page*? And why do you use the `Loader`?

Comment: @derM: I want to create views dynamically. Each view have grid and each grid holds up to 6 items. If the item count is more than 6 I need to display the item in another view with Swipe and page indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:
`lm` is the `ListModel` that is to be split.

```
SwipeView {
    width: 200
    height: 800
    clip: true
    currentIndex: 0

    Repeater {
        model: Math.ceil(lm.count / 6)
        delegate:            ListView {
            width: 200
            height: 800
            property int viewIndex: index
            model: DelegateModel {
                model: lm
                groups: DelegateModelGroup { name: 'filter' }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    for (var i = viewIndex * 6; i < lm.count && i < (viewIndex * 6) + 6; i++) {
                        items.setGroups(i, 1, ['items', 'filter'])
                    }
                }

                filterOnGroup: 'filter'

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 180
                    height: 30
                    border.width: 1
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And don't use a `Loader` as a delegate. The delegates are instantiated dynamically, so the `Loader` is just useless overhead. You might use a `Loader` within your delegate for parts, that are usually not shown.

Comment: In the swipeView I created GridViews dynamically. But, I have faced an issue while scroll to second View in the SwipeView. That is, while scroll to 2nd page, 1st screen contents are showing. How can I fix the issue.

Comment: set `clip:true`

Comment: You should also manually update the model for the repeater (count / 6 thingy). As the 'modelChanged'-Signal is only emitted, if the value changes, it won't be emitted until a new page is full. There are a couple of ways, I can think of, to do this.

Comment: I have set clip property for gridView ,  not worked :(

Comment: Yeah, set it at the SwipeView. I changed the example accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126095/discussion-between-vineesh-tp-and-derm).

Comment: is there any solution for the swipe issue ? :(

Comment: I went to the chat, you did not respond. What do you see: Two pages, oder only one, but the wrong page? Maybe you open a new Question and post a Screenshot, with what you have - and describe what you want to get. Would be easier than guessing what your problem might be.